# XSLT 1.0 String Length - 2

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, string-length

I need to check the length of a field and then add `.` before last two 
digits.

Example: the value of `Amount` is `0001234567`, to be replaced as `00012345.67`. Here string length will be 10.

But the command fails and is not able to  retrieve the  value from
`($VARAmtLength-2)` or `($VARAmtLength-1)`.

My code as below:

```
<xsl:variable name="VARAmtLength" select="string-length (ns0:Amount )"/>
<xsl:if test=" ($VARAmtLength> 0)">
    <tns:Amount>            
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(ns0:Amount, 1, ($VARAmtLength- 2)),'.', substring(ns0:Amount, ($VARAmtLength-1, 2)))"/>
    </tns:Amount>
</xsl:if>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is working fine.

Just replace this line with existing one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(ns0:Amount, 1, ($VARAmtLength - 2)),'.', substring(ns0:Amount, ($VARAmtLength - 1), 2))" />
```

**1.** There should be a space around subtraction operator '-'. Otherwise it will consider `$VARAmtLength-` as variable name.

**2.** You had misplaced round parentheses for second `substring()` function.

Answer (score -1):

XML

```xml
<amount>0001234567</amount>
```

Xsl

```xml
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="length" select="//amount"/>
    <xsl:if test="$length>0">
    <amount>
        <xsl:variable name="ajeet" select="concat(substring(//amount, 1, 8), '.')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="kumar" select="substring(//amount, 9, 2)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($ajeet, $kumar)"/>
    </amount>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```